# Замена символа в JS Photoshop

Tags: javascript, photoshop

В `сценарии` для `фотошопа` можно использовать функцию `replace`?

```
var layerName = activeDocument.activeLayer.name;
layerName.replace('-', '_');
```

В `фотошопе` `replaceAll` не хочет работать. Решение проблемы:

```
layerName = layerName.split('-').join('_');
```

Comment: Попробуйте ```layerName = layerName.replace('-', '_');```

Comment: Да. Немного тупанул. А если нужно сделать с 2 символами, то просто продублировать функцию или есть replace для множества символов?

Comment: `replaceAll`...?

Comment: Думаю можно продолжить цепочку.. ```replace().replace()```

Comment: Да `replaceAll`. `replace` заменит же только один символ?

Comment: Если нужно несколько, можно попробовать регулярные выражения с флагом глобальной замены: `layerName = layerName.replace(/-/g, '_');`